# JavaFX2: What is the best way to style an individual TreeItem?

Tags: css, treeview, javafx-2

I would have liked to have the ability to add a CSS class to the TreeItem and then just use a CSS file to give it style.   But that is not possible, or is it?

Is there a way to add a class like we can using getStyleClass()?

If not, what is the best way to give individual items a style?

Answer (score 1):

Best way to give style to items is use of stylesheets, limit use of Node.setStyle.

You may wonder why?

Reason is a performance. Calculate style values are cached. All Nodes that match the same selectors can share the calculculate value.

Comment: Yes, I meant to use stylesheets.  But the thing is: how can I assign a style class to a node that has no "getStyleClass()" function?  Like is the case with TreeItem or TableColumn among others.

Answer (score 1):

Well... Think outside the box! You can't style treeitem and tablerow because they act basically as a form of containers to other nodes, so set a class for the nodes on your treeitem (or tablerow) and then style them. I'm sorry by the answer, but I can't add comments yet

Comment: Thanks for the idea.  This would work if I had some way to refresh the list manually.  As it is now, the nodes are only refreshed once at the beginning unless the observable value changes.  I have filed a feature request in Jira that has been accepted for this.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [TreeCellFactory](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/TreeView.html#setCellFactory%28javafx.util.Callback%29) , and in the factory, use a Node and set it's style, either via getStyle, or even better via Node.setStyleClass.

Comment: This is what I do.  But as I told @Bruno,  it is just called once at the beginning