# JavaFX : color individual TreeItems using css

Tags: css, javafx, treeview

I want to be able to color individual Tree Item of treeView based on some condition.
This answer seems good but I am unable to implement it.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/10931896/6653207

I am unable to understand how to use `setCellFactory` method to format individual `TreeItem`s.

I have a class

```
public class Bag {
    public String caption,assignment="";
    Boolean eval;
    public Set<Vertex> Nodes = new HashSet<Vertex>();
    public Vector<Bag> ChildBags = new Vector<Bag>();

     @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return assignment+ " " +caption;
    }

}
```

Here's my css file:

```css
.true{
    -fx-text-fill:#33cc00 ;
}
.assignment{
    -fx-text-fill: #0033cc
}
```

So I want to color to green the caption ( the `toString()` method returns ) of all those nodes whose eval property is true.
and assignment string which `toString()` method returns  for all the nodes should be blue.

How can I do so?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By overriding the `updateItem` method of the `TreeCell`, you can adjust the `TreeCell`'s properties based on the value of the `TreeItem` the cell contains.

In the following example a pseudoclass is assigned to all cells that contain a value with the prefix `"child"` and all empty cells get a black background.

```
TreeView<String> treeView = ...

PseudoClass childPseudoClass = PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("child");

treeView.setCellFactory(tv -> new TreeCell<String>() {

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        if (empty || item == null) {
            // update for empty cell / cell containing null
            pseudoClassStateChanged(childPseudoClass, false);
            setText("");
            setStyle("-fx-background-color: black;");
        } else {
            // update for filled cell
            pseudoClassStateChanged(childPseudoClass, item.startsWith("child"));
            setText(item);
            setStyle(null);
        }
    }

});
```

**CSS Stylesheet**

```
.tree-cell:child {
    -fx-background-color: red;
}
```

---

The `updateItem` method is called by the `TreeView` every time the value changes, e.g. if a new `TreeItem` is associated with the cell or the `value` property of a `TreeItem` is modified.

You could also use the factory to add listeners to the `TreeCell`, before it's returned, in case you prefer this and e.g. want to change the cell based on the [`treeItem` property](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TreeCell.html#treeItemProperty).

---

**EDIT:** To apply different colors to the text, you need to use different `Node`s for the text parts.

```
treeView.setCellFactory(tv -> new TreeCell<Bag>() {

    private final Text assignment;
    private final Text caption;
    private final Node graphic;

    {
        assignment = new Text();
        caption = new Text();
        assignment.getStyleClass().add("assignment");
        graphic = new HBox(4, assignment, caption);
        setGraphic(graphic);
    }

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(Bag item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        if (empty || item == null) {
            setGraphic(null);
        } else {
            setGraphic(graphic);
            assignment.setText(item.assignment);
            caption.setText(item.caption);
            caption.getStyleClass().remove("true");
            if (item.eval) {
                caption.getStyleClass().add("true");
            }
        }
    }

});
```

To color the text you need to use the `-fx-fill` property instead of the `-fx-text-fill` property.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.I have a Treeview of Bag. Can I set different styles to different components of the  Bag (see edited question) i.e. assignment string to be blue and nodes whose eval is true set caption to green

Comment: I dont know why it doesn't work..please check the full code here:http://pastebin.com/4p7x9vh5

Comment: @HimaniVirmani: You're assigning the `caption` color using `setStyle`, but you're clearing the style classes to remove it. Use `setStyle(null)` instead. Furthermore you're still using `-fx-text-fill` instead of `-fx-fill`, which won't work for `Text` nodes.

Comment: Thanks it worked.But why do we need to put initialization of assignment and caption in separate block? and why is HBox required?

Comment: @HimaniVirmani Why different `Text` elements? Because you cannot use different colors with the same `Text` element. Why `HBox`? The `graphic` is only a single `Node` and therefore the `Text` elements need to be placed in a `Parent`. `HBox` provides suitable layout for this (you may need to switch to `TextFlow` for multiline text).

Comment: i am getting the following exceptions while trying to run the code:[link](http://pastebin.com/rRQ83Wmz). and the exceptions are:[link](http://pastebin.com/zsCxvFYz). I tried to print out the bag to check if tree was created properly and it was fine so i guess there is some problem in view logic.Can you tell me the problem?

Comment: Here's what I have observed : when i try to expand a subtree,the first subtree I try to expand gets expanded correctly and remaining don't expand even if there is a subtree below them. And if I set them all expanded by default it shows exceptions without showing the root.

Comment: @HimaniVirmani: The only source of an exception in the code is the `if(item.eval)` which will be compiled to the same bytecode as `if(item.eval.booleanValue())`. I assumed `item.eval` was always assigned, but if it's not, you need to add a check for `null`

Comment: Thanks. Corrected it.I was not initializing eval variable.But now collapsing after expanding does not remove the arrows.As far as I think:`if (empty || item == null) {
            assignment.setText("");
            caption.setText("");
        }` this does not remove the arrows. Also can you suggest some tutorials for me to learn this topic.

Comment: I used the SetGraphic Property inside the if else condition instead of doing it outside and it works now.